How to do simple file search in VSCODE
I am new to VScode. Whenever I try to search and click on a file it starts showing the diff view.
Here is a screenshot of the issue : https://prnt.sc/YZtk1gNm02S-

Are you on the git tab or the file explorer tab?

That screenshot doesn't really help since it just shows the result. How are you doing the search? Please [edit] to clarify. Also, please use the builtin image upload.

Oh, the problem is you're using Search and Replace. You just need to toggle off the Replace box.

BTW, "file search" isn't a very clear term; it could mean Search across files (AKA "Find in files") or "search file names", which is how DaviHlav misinterpreted it in his answer.

To do global file search in your project directory you have shortcuts:

On Windows Ctrl+p or Ctrl+e
On macOS Cmd ⌘+p

And then just type in the file you're looking for.
